# Intent URI to launch Gmail App

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any URI which can point to the GMAIL App in android and help me launch it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm using this in my apps:

```
Intent mailClient = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mailClient.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivity");
startActivity(mailClient);
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I was looking for it since a long time.

Comment: That is undocumented, unsupported, and may well break in the future.

Comment: Targeting API 17 I'm getting a `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` Any ideas?

Comment: Getting the launch intent for the package, as indicated [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7249579/421049), works for me.

Comment: Calling `setPackage("com.google.android.gm")`, which is available since ICS, is undocumented as well, but is very unlikely to break as the package name will probably not change.

Comment: Undocummented way. You should not use this

Comment: @CommonsWare Currently my implementation is showing the Google drive also. Is there any updated methods by which i can launch just the gmail app

Comment: @garret use 
mailClient.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");

Comment: Now its not working....can use:    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.gm");
startActivity(intent);

Comment: The 2nd parameter (`className`) is `"com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivityGmail"` for the time of writing (Gmail v6.7, Marshmallow).

Answer (score 74):

This works to intent just the gmail app.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setType("plain/text")
    .setData(Uri.parse("test@gmail.com"))
    .setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail")
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"test@gmail.com"})
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "test")
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello. this is a message sent from my demo app :-)");
startActivity(intent);
```

use for plenty of emails:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "test@gmail.com" });
```

for single emails:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("test@gmail.com"));
```

You may add `extra putExtra(Intent.EXTRA..)`  and change the `setType` for your purpose. :P

**Update (1/22/14):**
It is important to note that if you are going to use this code, you check to make sure that the user has the package "com.google.android.gm" installed on their device. In any language, make sure to check for null on specific Strings and initializations.

Please see [Launch an application from another application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application/15465797#15465797)

[image]

Comment: works nicely! also sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("abc@gmail.com")); seems to be needless.

Comment: Does anyone know why it has to be new String[] { "abc@gmail.com" } instead of just "abc@gmail.com" for the 2nd parameter?

Comment: It is a String array, it allows for multiple emails to be added.

Comment: There are downvotes because setting the package manually to "com.google.android.gm" is undocumented, and could potentially break if the package name ever changes or is not installed.

Comment: @LocalPCGuy Are you new to Android or just Java? You never copy and paste code from here. You need to modify it for 'null' checks. Make sure that package exists before you intent to that specified activity.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Both (but not programming in general), but I was leaving the comment because of the first comment you made, why it is getting minus 1 (I read that as downvotes).  I don't copy/paste code from anywhere without understanding it first personally, but you and I know that is the exception and if checking for null package is a requirement it should state that in the message (which I see now it does, great!)

Comment: This part is not needed:  sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("test@gmail.com"));

Over all working fine and save me a lot of time.. :) Thank you!

Comment: @LocalPCGuy Is there a way of sending the email without specifying this line? - intent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");  I'm getting a security error stating that the activity was not found.

Comment: Not really sure @Anon - I've not been working on Android since about the time this was originally posted. Maybe JaredBurrows can help.

Comment: This used to work. I am getting Security exception since quite some time now. Perhaps earlier the 'ComposeActivityGmail' was exported & now it is not.

Comment: @Swas_99 Which API level?

Comment: @Jared : API level 19

Comment: Odd, I would expect an exception on a higher level device. Maybe there is a better way, just using an intent resolver for all email apps instead of this one directly.

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=test@gmail.com cmp=com

Comment: @IrfanRaza did you find solution for java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=test@gmail.com cmp=com  ? If yes the please tell me the solution.

Comment: Use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21700622/7213349

Comment: Working solution: Instead of `setClassName`, use `setPackage("com.google.android.gm")`

Answer (score 23):

Using package name is not recommended as its an undocumented method. In case if the package name changes some day the code will fail.

Try this code instead

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
 "mailto", "abc@gmail.com", null));
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "This is my subject text");
 context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, null));
```

Ref:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO\

Comment: Use try catch block to prevent crash if package name changes in future. But setting package name gives better UX, so for gmail we should go with package

Answer (score 21):

Use this:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.gm");
startActivity(intent);
```

This could be device and API level dependent. Use with care.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i pass emails to gmail search box via above intent?

Comment: Haven't touched Android in a long time! I am not sure.

Answer (score 17):

Simple and 100 % working

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"anyMail@gmail.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Any subject if you want");
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
    startActivity(intent);
else
    Toast.makeText(this,"Gmail App is not installed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 12):

Later the requirements changed to starting an "Email app", so the below code basically starts an email app and the user has to choose among the choices shown up.

So, I had to use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Emailing link");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Link is \n" +
        "This is the body of hte message");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

Comment: If you see clearly what droid_fan has answered then it launches email app only on particular devices but my answer launches the email app no matter what the platform is.

Comment: +1 for the alternative.  Having looked again perhaps Richard Lalancette's answer provides a more generic solution for launching packages with unknown launch intent details.

Comment: This will also show things like PayPal in the intent picker. May not be what you want users to see.

Answer (score 12):

## Try this

i have tried to many solutions but finally i got a correct way that works fine for me

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("mailto:" + "your_emailid@gmail.com"));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "your_subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "your_text");
    startActivity(intent);
} catch(Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(Share.this, "Sorry...You don't have any mail app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

## Note

- This will open your installed mail application(***Email***,***Gmail***) to send mail in which you can select one among them.
- Don't use direct package name like("com.google.android.gm") because in future if they change package name your app will face problems.

Comment: It worked, Thanks. Didn't had to stumble on other options, found this quickly.

Answer (score 8):

This trick work for ALL version (API 3+), as well as **text/plain** or **text/html** (by [sonida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1017653/sonida)) :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
// intent.setType("text/plain");
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
ResolveInfo best = null;
for (final ResolveInfo info : matches) {
    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm") || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail")) {
        best = info;
        break;
    }
}
if (best != null) {
    intent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName, best.activityInfo.name);
}
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "YOUR SUBJECT");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("YOUR EXTRAS"));

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 6):

It works.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

String[] strTo = { getString(R.string.mailto) };

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, strTo);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.mail_subject));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.mail_body));

Uri attachments = Uri.parse(image_path);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachments);

intent.setType("message/rfc822");

intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");

startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it, is by using the generic way/method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("plain/text");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email Subject goes here");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your Message goes here");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""));
```

This will give the users a choice where they can pick GMail (if installed) or any other email supporting app they have.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the following code it'll open default mail composer automatically.

```
try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
        context.startActivity(intent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        handleException();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I was just interested in opening the email client not composing a new email.

Answer (score 2):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"+mailId)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its working code perfectly.....

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            String[] strTo = { "test@g.com" };
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, strTo);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
            intent.setType("message/rfc822");
            intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: it's 2023 and Android changed `getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities()` to no longer return the GMail package. But priyanka's code still works because the GMail package still has the literal package name `com.google.android.gm`.

Answer (score 1):

Working as for me is just simple like this:

```
 Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply{
            setPackage("com.google.android.gm")
            type = "text/plain"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Go, go share text!")
        }.also{readyIntent->
            startActivity(readyIntent)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet will open a chooser which is supposed to point to Gmail inbox.

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL)
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.open_email_app)))
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    showErrorDialog(R.string.error_activity_is_not_found)
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither was working for me, as the subject and message were always empty, until I found the official solution [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Email).

```
fun composeEmail(addresses: Array<String>, subject: String, attachment: Uri) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
        type = "*/*"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses)
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment)
    }
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is old,but still appears in the Google Search at first position.

Hence,from the android documentation,the better way to do this now is :

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject, Uri attachment) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

More information can be found out at [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common?utm_source=udacity&utm_medium=course&utm_campaign=android_basics)

Answer (score 0):

```
final String package = "com.google.android.gm";
// return true if gmail is installed
boolean isGmailInstalled = isAppInstalled(MainActivity.this, package);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"mail@gamil.com"});
if (isGmailInstalled) {
    intent.setType("text/html");
    intent.setPackage(package);
    startActivity(intent);
} else {  // allow user to choose a different app to send email with
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "choose an email client"));
}

// Method to check if app is installed
private boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent URI to launch Gmail App

```
Intent mailClient = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mailClient.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivityGmail");
startActivity(mailClient);
```