# On Android, how can I launch the Gmail App to display a specific mail?

Tags: android, gmail

My scenario is like this:
(1)I found a mail(Gmail) which is very useful.
(2)I send the URL of this mail to my app on android.
(3)In my app, I launch the Gmail App to display this specific mail.
I don't know how to launch the Gmail App to display the URL of this specific mail.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intent URI to launch Gmail App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470042/intent-uri-to-launch-gmail-app)

Comment: Perhaps this question will be of help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470042/intent-uri-to-launch-gmail-app

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can open the Gmail app on an specific mail. You can open the app for sure using Intents, but not an specific mail.

Comment: Actually, I tried to use browser to open the URL of the specific mail, but I can only get into the "inbox". That's why I want to try the Gmail App.

Comment: Yes, I tried before, but there's more than that: for something like this to happen, the GMAIL app must support it. The problem is not with Android, but with the GMAIL app. If they don't provide a hook so you can pass a URL and they open that email, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score -1):

This never was answered so I'll add one:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "abc@gmail.com" });
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("abc@gmail.com"));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "enter subject");
sendIntent.setType("plain/text");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Insert text");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

This is from my answer here: [Intent URI to launch Gmail App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470042/intent-uri-to-launch-gmail-app/7456162#7456162)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: @SteveBlackwell This was posted 6 years ago.