# How to send data to a particular app?

Tags: android, data-exchange

I am building an application where there are many Gmail ID of client.

I need when any user click on a particular client ID then it pass to Other selective application like hangout/Gtalk and they can chat there.

Comment: Maybe this can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470042/intent-uri-to-launch-gmail-app

Comment: If that's your answer, I will make it an answer and you can accept it so this question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you. You should be able to do what you need via an Intent.

[Intent URI to launch Gmail App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470042/intent-uri-to-launch-gmail-app)