# Why specify an intent-filter when we already specify the activity in setClassName?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setType("plain/text");
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("test@gmail.com"));
sendIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "test@gmail.com" });
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "test");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello. this is a message sent from my demo app :-)");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

In the code above (from [this answer by Jared Burrows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456162/208273)) I am confused why we have to specify the action: `ACTION_VIEW` in the `sendIntent` definition? We already specified that the activity that we want to start using the `sendIntent` intent is the `"com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail"` activity.

I thought the only purpose of the action `ACTION_VIEW` would be if you are making an implicit intent and you want the system to display all of the applications that the user downloaded that have an `Activity` that can perform the action `ACTION_VIEW`?

But in this case we already specified which activity we want to start which is `ComposeActivityGmail` so why put the `ACTION_CLOSE` action since the system would already which activity to start for this intent.

Comment: Never mind that specific class `ComposeActivityGmail` may use the action in the Activity to perform something different even though the same activity may be used for different actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code to start another activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Classname.class);
startService(intent);
```

You use `ACTION_VIEW` with `startActivity()` when you have some information that an activity can show to the user, such as a photo to view in a gallery app, or an address to view in a map app.

In your case, you are passing the email address so that is why you have to use it.

Comment: The `ComposeActivityGmail` is used for `ACTION_VIEW` as well as `ACTION_SEND`. So when the `ComposeActivityGmail` receives an intent, in the code that handles the handle in the `ComposeActivityGmail` does it use the Action in the intent to perform some specific behavior? Like for `ACTION_VIEW` it will only show the user something. `ACTION_SEND` it will actually send the message.

Comment: Yes, the action in the intent performs specific behavior. `Intent.getAction()` in the second activity( here `ComposeActivityGmail` ) retrieves the general action to be performed and it does get influenced by `ACTION_VIEW` or `ACTION_SEND`.